# Javascript Multi Array with 3 Selection Boxes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need some help with my javascript. I am trying to make a multiple array that does the following:

Select Instance >
Choose a boss from that instance >
Select Mode for the above boss, but not all bosses have the same modes.

So some how i have to put in the mode array for inside the boss array

Also how would i add the a boss id. So that the selection box value is the id, and the displayed text is what it is currently the name.

my code is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ABjEY/4/

Thanks for any help.

Edit: updated URL. I have added the parts mightyuhu said, but i cannot now show the names / ids and i am not sure how to still populate the 3rd selection box.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to assign your bosses to the modes available, you can do that i.e. by adding a "availableModes" parameter  to the bosses and list the indexes of the modes available there.

```
    {"Instance":"The Battle of Ilum",
     "Boss": [{name:"Velasu Graege",availableModes:[1,2,3]},... },...
```

by the same principle you may add a specific boss-Id

Comment: I have updated my question any more help would be awesome, thanks